# International Driver's license in US

Tags: usa, driving-licenses

I have a family member from Malaysia who will be staying with us for 3 months. Before I contact the Insurance Company (Metromile), I want to know if I can add him to the car insurance temporarily, what is normally the best advice to allow him to drive, and in case of an accident we are covered?

Comment: Speaking exclusively of Washington State, where I reside. You can drive up to one year with a foreign license before needing to apply for a Washington driver's license, as a visitor. If you plan to become a resident of the state, you must get a license within 30 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding driver license it depends on the single states you will drive in. 
International Driver License is sometimes not recognized by the law, so your friend's usual license is enough.

For example in California:

> The State of California does not recognize an International Driving Permit (IDP) as a valid driver license (DL). California does recognize a valid driver license that is issued by a foreign jurisdiction (country, state, territory) of which the license holder is a resident.

quote from [dmv.ca.gov](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/dl/dl_info#international)

Regarding the insurance I think the best way to go is to contact the insurance company and ask, for sure you will find much better and precise information than on a forum.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong: acceptance doesn't "depend on the state you will drive in." No state recognizes the International Drivers Permit as a license: the IDP is a translation only, and only valid when accompanied by a valid license issued by one of the contracting countries, or states within those countries. When these conditions are met, contracting countries (and states within them which issue drivers licenses) must accept the traveler's homeland DL + IDP as a valid license to drive.

Comment: I didn't say acceptance depends... Before commenting a 1.5 years old post, read more carefully

Comment: What's different about your words "it depends?" The US is a signatory to the treaty, so if you're referring to US states, then there is no "depends" at all. An individual state does not have the authority to refuse the validity of a valid overseas license plus an IDP, if they come from another signatory state.